# jquery queue problem part 2

Tags: jquery

i got a problem again..

```
 $(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"},
 function() {
     $(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"});
     $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
 }); 
 $(".menu-container").hide(function(){
     $(".webPageFrame").attr("src","");                
     addMenuButtons('main-menu',MenuTitleMain);

     addLastMenuButtons('last-menu','Login');

     menuBordersAndCorners('main-menu');
     lastMenuBordersAndCorners('last-menu');
 });
      $(".menu-container").show();
      $(".menu-container").animate({top:"0px"});
```

i think the last 2 lines are not executing.. i have not seen the .menu-container and did not animate to top:0px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part:

```
 $(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}, function() {
   $(".menu-container").animate({top:"-900px"});
   $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
 });
```

You are queuing the `.animate({top:"-900px"});` *after* the `.animate({top:"0px"});` has been queued at the bottom, you need to get it on the queue stack before then, like this:

```
 $(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}, function() {
   $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
 }).animate({top:"-900px"});
```

Currently here's what's happening:

1. `.menu-container` *starts* animating to `top: 25px`
2. `.menu-container` **queues** the `top: 0px` animation`
3. When `.menu-container` *finishes* animating to `top: 25px` it **then** queues the `top: -900px` animation.

So the result is it's animating to 25, 0 then -900, because of the order items are inserted into the queue.  I'm still not sure that the `hide()` and `show()` order are what you're after, but that's the reason you're not seeing the element, it's ending up 900px above the window :)

**Update:** Based on comments, I think this is closer to what you're after:

```
$(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}, function() {
     $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
 }).animate({top:"-900px"}, function(){
     $(".webPageFrame").attr("src","");                
     addMenuButtons('main-menu',MenuTitleMain);
     addLastMenuButtons('last-menu','Login');
     menuBordersAndCorners('main-menu');
     lastMenuBordersAndCorners('last-menu');
 }).animate({top:"0px"});
```

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) (when not giving a duration > 0) aren't queued, so happen immediately...this does the work once it's 900px out of view.

Comment: $(".menu-container").animate({top:"25px"}, function() {
          $(".windows-container").animate({top:"-730px"});
        }).animate({top:"-900px"},changeThisValue());
     function changeThisValue()
     {
     $(".webPageFrame").attr("src","");                
     addMenuButtons('main-menu',MenuTitleMain);  
     addLastMenuButtons('last-menu','Login'); 
     menuBordersAndCorners('main-menu');
     lastMenuBordersAndCorners('last-menu'); 
     }                           
     $(".menu-container").animate({top:"0px"});
but seems.. it changes even if still visible..

Comment: @user - You mean the content changes while it's still visible?

Comment: sorry sir.. but i cant format well my comment.. i dont know how.. i got only plain textarea and dont have any buttons for formating to code..

Comment: @vrynxzent:  I updated the answer with the approach I think you're after, give it a shot.